# extract the string that comes after a question mark in URL

Tags: javascript

If anyone could help me with me this, it would very appreciative.

I'm trying to extract the string that comes after the last question mark ('rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr' in the following example):

from:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/url=https://sites.google.com/a/yink.net/uok/ee.xml&container=enterprise&view=default&lang=en&country=ALL&sanitize=0&v=9a2d7691ff90daec&libs=core&mid=38&parent=http://j.yink.net/home/sandbox?**rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr**

to:

> rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

I've tried this code, but it doesn't give the right result:

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = window.location.search.slice(1);

Comment: regex to this would be: `urlString.match(".*\\?(.*)")[1]`

Answer (score 2):

`var url = window.location.href` will give you the URL

Then you'll want to grab everything after the `?` using

`var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);`

I pieced the answer together from: https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

**Edit:** -------------------------------------

To get the text after the last question mark then you can use:

`url.split('?').pop()` instead of `url.split('?')[1]`

(Credit to: *@I wrestled a bear once* )

Comment: Thanks Badrush!

I need to extract the text only from the *last* question mark. I have several question marks in the URL...

Comment: @Eli - if you want to use the split method you could use `url.split('?').pop()` instead of `url.split('?')[1]` and you'll get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get the last index of the "?" and then use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get the substring.

Make sure you sanitize the string and make sure there is a "?" in it first or else it will throw an error.

```js
let str = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/url=https://sites.google.com/a/yink.net/uok/ee.xml&container=enterprise&view=default&lang=en&country=ALL&sanitize=0&v=9a2d7691ff90daec&libs=core&mid=38&parent=http://j.yink.net/home/sandbox?rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr`;

console.log(str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("?")+1));
```